# How i can Create CustomLog File When I Add Product to Cart

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

How I can Create CustomLog File  When I Add a Product to a Cart
in Magento 2 how I can create a customlog when I add a product into the cart and create all the available product custom log

I have no solution about

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's split the requirement into 2 parts.

1. Create Custom log file.
2. Add Observer to catch the Add to cart event and use the custom log file in the observer

Create **handler.php** to define the path and custom log file.

***Sathya/CustomLog/Logger/Handler.php***

```php
<?php

namespace Sathya\CustomLog\Logger;

use Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\Base;
use Monolog\Logger;

class Handler extends Base
{
    protected $loggerType = Logger::INFO;

    protected $fileName = '/var/log/custom_log_file.log';
}
```

Next, create the Logger.php to inject into the Observer

***Sathya/CustomLog/Logger/Logger.php***

```php
<?php

namespace Sathya\CustomLog\Logger;

class Logger extends \Monolog\Logger
{

}
```

Pass the necessary argument which supports the logger for file systems.
Create **di.xml**

***Sathya/CustomLog/etc/di.xml***

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Sathya\CustomLog\Logger\Handler">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="filesystem" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Sathya\CustomLog\Logger\Logger">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">Sathya_CustomLog</argument>
            <argument name="handlers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="system" xsi:type="object">Sathya\CustomLog\Logger\Handler</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

---

Event And Observer

1. Event to catch the Add to Cart

Create events.xml ***Sathya/CustomLog/etc/events.xml***

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="custom_log_file_observer"
                  instance="Sathya\CustomLog\Observer\AddToCart"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

In the Observer inject the logger and use the Custom Logger file & handle the logic what to happen when add to cart event triggered.

Create observer, AddTocart.php ***Sathya/CustomLog/Observer/AddToCart.php***

```php
<?php

namespace Sathya\CustomLog\Observer;


use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Sathya\CustomLog\Logger\Logger;

class AddToCart implements ObserverInterface
{

    public function __construct(
        Logger $logger

    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $this->logger->addInfo("Custom log file in the Observer");
        $quoteItems = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        // Logic what to do in the Observer

        $this->logger->addError("Custom log file in the Observer - Error");
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you to understand, please modify the module name as per your need.

Answer (score 1):

There is an event observer when a product is added to cart, please implement the event observer, the event name is - "checkout_cart_add_product_complete", please check out this link about this event

Link - https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/events-and-observers/event-list/#checkout_cart_add_product_complete

To implement an event in Magento 2, please create a basic module with registering it by creating a module.xml file and registration.php and enabling it to register it.

After that create an event observer by going through the below process:-

For creating the observer, please follow this code as an example, inside the execute you can modify the way you like to add more functionalities.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace OX\ProductEventLogger\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class ProductAddEventLogger implements ObserverInterface
{

    private $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer): void
    {
        $this->logger->debug('Product is added to cart');
    }
}
```

This is the events.xml file you should create inside the directory etc/frontend/events.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_add_product_complete">
        <observer name="ox_checkout_cart_add_product_complete"
                  instance="OX\ProductEventLogger\Observer\ProductAddEventLogger"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Overall this event observer is working in my system, this event observer will work when a product is added to the cart immediately.

If there is any doubt, you know what to do!

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you can use **event-observer**.

Please check my below answer.

**events.xml** : app\code\Vendor\Module\etc\events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

   <!-- add logic when item added to cart -->
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
     <observer name="pf_checkout_cart_product_add_after" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CheckoutCartAddObserver" />
    </event>


</config>
```

**CheckoutCartAddObserver**: app\code\Vendor\Module\Observer\CheckoutCartAddObserver.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

/**
 * CheckoutCartAddObserver
 */
class CheckoutCartAddObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
       \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
    $this->logger = $logger;
    }
    
    /**
     * execute
     *
     * @param EventObserver observer
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $this->logger->info("this is custom log");
    }
}
```